# Resetting User Password When User Email is Not Stored in "User" Class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, backend

**BACKGROUND INFO:**

*This question concerns the Parse Javascript SDK*

By default, Parse.com stores users' email addresses in the pre-defined "User" class. Although one can use CLPs and/or ACLs to restrict access to the "User" class objects, it seems impossible (even using **Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()** in cloud code) to create a functional app that fulfills my needs without allowing public read access on the "User" class.

This means that users' email addresses would be perfectly accessible by anyone with a rudimentary understanding of javascript (an obvious deal-breaker). To avoid this problem, I decided to create a separate class that holds users' email addresses, with pointers to their respective "User" class objects. I'm able to completely lock down these new "Email" class objects while maintaining the functionality that my app requires, using CLPs and ACLs.

But this causes a new problem: Parse's [method](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-resetting) for allowing a user to request a password-reset -- [Parse.User.requestPasswordReset()](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.User.html#.requestPasswordReset) -- apparently requires that their email address be set on the "User" class.

In trying to circumvent the problem, I explored using Parse.com's "Mandrill" cloud code module to handle the password-reset email paradigm myself. But this doesn't seem to solve the problem, as Parse.com would still need to register whether or not the user clicked the reset-password link in the email they received -- something I've no idea how to accomplish.

**QUESTION:**

Is there a way to reset a user's password when their email address is stored in a class other than "User"? If not, how would one use Parse.com as a back end without exposing their users' email addresses?

Comment: Had the same question written down & about to click post! Anyway, did you find a way to address this issue?

Comment: @IsaacBhasme For my purposes, I was (eventually) able to keep email addresses in the User class as intended instead of using a different class. I set the User class CLP to Public --> Write --> Update/Create (not Delete), and when a new user is created, their User object's ACL specifies no public access whatsoever. I then had to alter some of my client-side javascript to make this work for me.